# Rails simple SQL search -> uninitialized constant error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

OK, so I have a file structure like this (including pertinent parts)

```
| app -
      | lib -
            | search.rb
      |
      | models -
               |
               | api -
                     | 
                     | people.rb
```

I hope that isn't too bad of a diagram.

I'm trying to create a search library that will search `people.name` with a `LIKE` query.

```
# /app/models/api/people.rb
class Api::People < ActiveRecord::Base
end

# /app/lib/search.rb
class Search
def Search.execute(param)
  @people = Api::People.find(:all, :conditions => ["name LIKE ?", param])
end

private
end
```

Now, as you can probably tell, I'm a beginner. When I try to run my `rake spec` command with this spec

```
# /spec/lib/search_spec.rb
require_relative '../../app/lib/search.rb'

describe Search do
  it "is instantiable" do
    @search = Search.new()
    expect(@search).not_to eql(nil)
  end

  it ".execute does not throw error" do
    @search = Search.execute("string")
  end
end
```

---

Error report: `rake spec`

```
Failures:

1) Search .execute does not throw error
 Failure/Error: @people = Api::People.find(:all, :conditions => ["name LIKE ?", param])

 NameError:
   uninitialized constant Search::Api
 # ./app/lib/search.rb:3:in `execute'
 # ./spec/lib/search_spec.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00118 seconds (files took 0.08766 seconds to load)
2 examples, 1 failure
```

I'm so confused as to this `Api::Search` constant. I tried moving the `people.rb` file out of the `models/api` folder, but then I got an `uninitialized constant Search::People` error. If you can please help, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Rails is adding folders in `app/` to autoload, though you may want to restart server (and may be do `spring stop` just in case).

As for specs, usually there's a `require 'rails_helper'` (or `spec_helper` if you are using RSpec v2), which adds Rails logic with autoload paths.

Your exception says that your `app/models/api/people` is not loaded.

Another options is to add this:

```
# /spec/lib/search_spec.rb
require_relative '../../app/lib/search.rb'
require_relative '../../app/models/api/people.rb'
```